# How to convert a LINQ query back to simple foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

1. How do I convert this back to a simple for each loop (for readability)
2. What alternatives can be done other than casting if an exception is faced?

   ```
   try
   {
        paymentPayloads = queueItems.Where(x => queueItemIds.Any(y => y == x.ItemId))
                                    .Select(x => (PaymentPayload)x.Payload)
                                    .ToList();
   }
   catch
   {
        throw new InvalidCastException();
   }
   ```

Basically earlier on in the class I loop through a list to check if each queueItem is valid

```
    var queueItemIds = new List<string>();
            foreach (var queueItem in queueItems)
            {
                var queueItemValidationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(queueItem);

                if (queueItemValidationResult.IsValid)
                {
                    queueItemIds.Add(queueItem.ItemId);
                }
                else
                {
                    var errorMessage = BuildErrorMessage(queueItemValidationResult.Errors);
                    var paymentPayload = (PaymentPayload)queueItem.Payload;

                    _logger.LogWarning($"Error for item id {queueItem.ItemId} with charge id {paymentPayload.ChargeId}: {Environment.NewLine} {errorMessage}");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I convert this back to a simple for each loop (for readability)

Translation should be fairly mechanical, just change it to a foreach loop. `.Where` becomes and if-statement, `.Select` picks the item etc. You might also consider using [iterator blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) to provide more functions or create an iterator that is lazily evaluated.

```
var result = new List<PaymentPayload>();
foreach(var x in queueItems){
    bool any = false;
    foreach(var y in queueItemIds){
        any |= y == x.ItemId;
    }
    if(any){
        result.Add((PaymentPayload)x.Payload);
    }
}
```

But I might not agree that this code is much more readable than the linq variant.

> What alternatives can be done other than casting if an exception is faced?

Check the type before using it

```
if(x.Payload is PaymentPayload pp) { // do things with pp}
```

Or use [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0) for the linq variant.

But you should in general be careful with code checking the type since it can result in code that is difficult to understand and fragile. If you are getting invalid cast exceptions then it means you have some incorrect understanding of how the code is intended to work and should correct that.

Comment: I'd agree the LINQ is more readable!

Comment: Your loop version is slightly different in that LINQ's `Any` will exit early if a true value is obtained, but yours will continue.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes, I was lazy and saved a few rows of code. It is intended as an example and not meant to be copied verbatim.